# Can SIFT run in realtime?

Tags: image-processing, local-features, sift, real-time

What is the best possible runtime for extracting SIFT keypoints and Descriptors?
I know it depends on #keypoints extracted. So, say for image of size 640x640, the code that I have been using requires around 3 seconds for description of ~2000 keypoints.

What is the best runtime achieved and how (on similar grounds)? How can I make it run in realtime?
Is hadoop with 100 clusters a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIFT implemented on a GPU can run in realtime!

http://cs.unc.edu/~ccwu/siftgpu/

Comment: What is the best runtime we can get for ~2000 keypoints on ~2.2GHz and RAM of 4GB? I have been using C++ code by Andrew Vedaldi and it takes around 3.5s for 2000 keypoints. Is there any implementation which does this within 1s with above configuration?